# Change the consolidate sources on the macro

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I´m trying to make a macro, everything was fine, but I´m having trouble to consolidate an sheet using the macro. It worked, but the problem is with the code, because, I consolidate a sheet in another sheet, but in the same workbook(file). But on the macro, it uses the file address on my computer, so if I change the file name or place, it won´t work. Please I really tried.
So, I need to consolidate the sheet "Controle Estoque Fixo" on the sheet "Analise de Estoque" and both are on the same file, so i need to remove the file source.

```
ActiveSheet.Select
ActiveSheet.Name = "Analise de Estoque"
Range("A1").Select
Selection.Consolidate Sources:= _
 "'C:\Users\rapha\Desktop\Cerealista\25062016\[Controle de Estoque v2.xlsm]Controle Estoque Fixo'!C1:C4", Function:=xlSum, _
TopRow:=True, LeftColumn:=True, CreateLinks:=False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to specify a path if the workbooks are open.

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Consolidate Sources:= _
                      "'[Controle de Estoque v2.xlsm]Controle Estoque Fixo'!R1C3:R4C3", Function:=xlSum, _
                      TopRow:=True, LeftColumn:=True, CreateLinks:=False
```

You don't have to specify a workbook if all worksheets are in the ActiveWorkbook.

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Consolidate Sources:= _
                      "'Controle Estoque Fixo'!C1:C4", Function:=xlSum, _
                      TopRow:=True, LeftColumn:=True, CreateLinks:=False
```

You can get the correct syntax by using Range().Address(, , xlR1C1, True)

> Worksheets("Controle Estoque Fixo").Range("C1:C4").Address( , ,xlR1C1,True)
>
> '[Book1.xlsm]Controle Estoque Fixo'!R1C3:R4C3